# The query I ran returns 2 of the same column which isn't allowed in tableau and I can't fix the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I need to be able to get rid of one of the workdate and one of the sr_name columns but I can't figure out how to.

I'm getting the query returned like this:
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vzyx.png)

I'm also getting this error message when entered into tableau:

```
   The column 'sr_name' was specified multiple times for 'Custom SQL Query'.
```

Below is the code I have. If I remove a sr_name from either subquery there will be an error in the join clause.

```
select * 
from
(
select s.sr_name, cast(punchdatetime as date) as workdate,
    ((datediff(second, min(case when p.InOut = 1 then punchdatetime end), 
    max(case when p.InOut = 0 then punchdatetime end))/3600) - .5) as 
    hoursworked
    from PunchClock p join ServiceReps s on p.ServRepID = s.ServRepID
    where punchyear >= 2019
    group by s.sr_name, cast(punchdatetime as date)
    ) v

join 
    (
    select sr_name, t.*,
    calls = (select count(*) from CRM_Correspondence cr where 
    cast(cr.DateCreated as date) = workdate and StatusType like '%call%' and 
    cr.ServRepID = t.servrepid),
    reaches = (select count(*) from CRM_Correspondence cr where 
    cast(cr.DateCreated as date) = workdate and (StatusType = 'call reached' 
    or StatusType like '%SCHEDULE%') and cr.ServRepID = t.servrepid),
    books = (select count(*) from os_appointments o where cast(o.DateCreated 
    as date) = workdate  and isnull(o.confirmedby, o.booked_by) = 
    t.servrepid),
    attends = (select count(*) from os_appointments o where 
    cast(o.DateCreated as date) = workdate  and isnull(o.confirmedby, 
    o.booked_by) = t.servrepid and o.appointmentStatus = 'attended')

from
    (
    select cast(cor.datecreated as date) workdate, cor.ServRepID
    from CRM_Correspondence cor
    where cor.datecreated > '2019-01-01'
    group by cast(cor.datecreated as date), cor.servrepid
    ) t
join ServiceReps sr on t.ServRepID = sr.ServRepID
) u on v.sr_name = u.sr_name and v.workdate = u.workdate
```

I need the same results just without the duplicate column so I can enter the query into tableau.

Comment: Don't use select *. You should always specify the columns by name. And in your case using * is causing you the problem. I would strongly suggest using some formatting in your queries. They are just a wall of text which are completely indecipherable.

Comment: There is formatting, it's just when I post it into here it limits the length of each line.

Comment: If I put specific columns in the select clause in the beginning then I get this error message:  The multi-part identifier "s.sr_name" could not be bound.

Comment: That is because you have created subquery hell here. The alias s is out of scope in the outer query. You have to use the alias v which is the alias for the subquery where that value resides. So it would be v.sr_name

Comment: Thank you, it really was that simple

Answer (score 2):

This is challenging because you have so many subqueries here. This could be refactored to use a single query which is what I would do. But using the existing query you could do something along these lines.

I had to format this very differently so I could isolate each piece.

```
select v.sr_name
    , v.workdate
    , v.hoursworked
    , u.ServRepID
    , u.calls
    , u.reaches
    , u.books
    , u.attends
from
(
    select s.sr_name
        , cast(punchdatetime as date) as workdate
        , ((datediff(second, min(case when p.InOut = 1 then punchdatetime end), max(case when p.InOut = 0 then punchdatetime end))/3600) - .5) as hoursworked
    from PunchClock p 
    join ServiceReps s on p.ServRepID = s.ServRepID
    where punchyear >= 2019
    group by s.sr_name
        , cast(punchdatetime as date)
) v
join 
(
    select sr_name
        , t.*
        , calls = 
                (
                    select count(*) 
                    from CRM_Correspondence cr 
                    where cast(cr.DateCreated as date) = workdate 
                        and StatusType like '%call%' 
                        and cr.ServRepID = t.servrepid
                )
        , reaches = 
                (
                    select count(*) 
                    from CRM_Correspondence cr 
                    where cast(cr.DateCreated as date) = workdate 
                        and (StatusType = 'call reached' or StatusType like '%SCHEDULE%') 
                        and cr.ServRepID = t.servrepid
                )
        , books = 
                (
                    select count(*) 
                    from os_appointments o 
                    where cast(o.DateCreated as date) = workdate  and isnull(o.confirmedby, o.booked_by) = t.servrepid
                )
        , attends = 
                (
                    select count(*) 
                    from os_appointments o 
                    where cast(o.DateCreated as date) = workdate
                        and isnull(o.confirmedby, o.booked_by) = t.servrepid 
                        and o.appointmentStatus = 'attended'
                )
    from
    (
        select cast(cor.datecreated as date) workdate
            , cor.ServRepID
        from CRM_Correspondence cor
        where cor.datecreated > '2019-01-01'
        group by cast(cor.datecreated as date)
            , cor.servrepid
    ) t
    join ServiceReps sr on t.ServRepID = sr.ServRepID
) u on v.sr_name = u.sr_name 
    and v.workdate = u.workdate
```